# How to order posts by date added

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a website in which admins can post news and updates but every time they add a new one it goes from the first one added downwards any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Could you give more details about which framework you are using?

Comment: @YanetPedraza its just adding posts to a MySQL table and then retrieving them on the dashboard would u like me to post the code?

Comment: Change ascending to descending? If that's what you mean.. order by ... desc

Comment: Add an `ORDER BY` to your SQL query...? This question is way too broad - voting to close.

Comment: @pbrianq order by date but I'm not sure how to add date to it

Comment: @Santi so if date variable was $date would it be ORDER BY $date

Comment: `ORDER BY` assumes *ascending* order. To sort dates with most recent first, you'll want `ORDER BY $date DESC`, which indicates "DESCENDING" order. But this is under the assumption that `$date` is the name of the column you want to sort by, and not a specific date. Again, please just do some research. This is one of the most basic functionalities of any RDBMS, and is covered at length in thousands of places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to sort on the datetime (or if that doesn't exist you could use the ID, but that is not how "it should be") in descending order instead of ascending.

Example query:

```
SELECT `title`, `text` FROM `news` ORDER BY `datetime` DESC LIMIT 5
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html